# Why does the third if else statement never gets executed?

Tags: c++

Why does line 17 never gets executed. I believe that it(if else statement) gets terminated as soon as it meets the first condition. If so, how to solve this problem. Are there any way to check all of the conditions?

```
#include <iostream>
/*
Why does the third if else statement never gets executed. I believe that 
it(if else statement) gets terminated as soon as it meets the first
condition. If so, how to solve this problem. Are there any way to check
all of the conditions?
*/

int main() //This check if you can drive a car or not
{
    int age;
    std::cout << "Enter your age: ";
    std::cin >> age;

    if (age >= 18)
        std::cout << "You can drive.\n";
    else if (age < 18)
        std::cout << "You have to be 18 to drive.\n";
    else if (age >= 80) // 80 and above should not drive
        std::cout << "You are too old to drive\n";
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is clearly C++ code, please don't apply the C tag to something that could never compile as C.

Answer (score 7):

Your first test is for `age >= 18`. Any age above `18` will pass, and none of the subsequent `else if` tests will even be checked. If you want this to work as intended, make sure to test `age >= 80` first, so the next test only separates the groups *below* 80, e.g.:

```
if (age >= 80)
    std::cout << "You are too old to drive\n";
else if (age < 18)
    std::cout << "You have to be 18 to drive.\n";
else  // Don't need a final if check; the previous two checks ensure if you get here, the age is between 18 and 79 inclusive
    std::cout << "You can drive.\n";
```

Comment: Wow! I have never thought that way. I certainly learned something new on how to structure it better. I just started learning 3 days ago so still dont know the best practises. And thank you very much.

Comment: @Kobor: You're welcome. To be clear, other orders are fully possible. But you need to make sure a test that would overlap two different categories never gets tested before the test it overlaps (or that you narrow the scope of the test to avoid the overlap). In the example above, you could test `age < 18` or `age >= 80` first (because neither of them identify values that belong to any other age group), *or* you could narrow the scope of the `age >= 18` test to explicitly require it also be `age < 80`, allowing you to put the tests in any order. I just showed one of the minimal test solutions.

Answer (score 4):

It won't ever reach the `age >= 80` since a value that large would always meet the requirement of `age >= 18` and the `else` tells it to only choose one option.

You could check the over 80 condition first to make sure it gets found.

```cpp
if (age >= 80) // 80 and above should not drive
    std::cout << "You are too old to drive\n";
else if (age >= 18)
    std::cout << "You can drive.\n";
else if (age < 18)
    std::cout << "You have to be 18 to drive.\n";
```

Or you could just add a condition to the first if statement so it won't apply to over 80.

```cpp
if (age >= 18 && age < 80)
    std::cout << "You can drive.\n";
else if (age < 18)
    std::cout << "You have to be 18 to drive.\n";
else if (age >= 80) // 80 and above should not drive
    std::cout << "You are too old to drive\n";
```

Comment: I didn't know that we can have two different conditions together. I wonder if we can do something like "if( x && x && x)" this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If `age >= 18` is false, then `age < 18` is true.

So, no matter what `age` is, the third `if` will never be reached.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).